# Text Color not changing in React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native

So I'm messing with React Native using Typescript, im trying to implement a dark mode system (once I have it working it will be going into Redux State) however, My Background is changing colour but my text is not.

I have seen [React Native Text color not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51663457/react-native-text-color-not-working) my state is updating because my background colour is changing.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, StatusBar, SafeAreaView, AsyncStorage, Button } from 'react-native';

export interface Props{
  name: string;
}

export interface State{
  darkmode: boolean;
  ready:boolean;
}

export interface DarkModeStyle{
  backgroundColor: string;
  color: string
}

export interface LightModeStyle{
  backgroundColor: string;
  color: string
}

export default class BeaconAppFrame extends React.Component<Props, State>{
  private styles;

  public state : State = {
    darkmode:false,
    ready:false
  }

  public darkModeStyle : DarkModeStyle = {
    backgroundColor:"#555", 
    color:"#EEE"
  }

  public lightModeStyle : LightModeStyle = {
    backgroundColor:"#FFF",
    color:"#000"
  }

  constructor(props: Props){
    super(props);

    // setup the default frame styles
    this.styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
      }
    });
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    AsyncStorage.getItem('darkmode').then( (darkmode) => {
      this.setState({darkmode:darkmode === "yes", ready:true});
    }).catch(() => {
      this.setState({darkmode:false, ready:true});
      AsyncStorage.setItem("darkmode", "no");
    });
  }

  enableDarkMode(){
    this.setState({"darkmode":!this.state.darkmode});
    AsyncStorage.setItem("darkmode", this.state.darkmode?"yes":"no");
  }

  render(){
    if(this.state.ready){
      let style = [this.styles.container, this.state.darkmode?this.darkModeStyle:this.lightModeStyle];
      console.log(style);
      return (
        <SafeAreaView style={style}>
          <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" hidden={true} translucent={false} />
          <Text>darkmode is set to {this.state.darkmode? "Active":"Inactive"}</Text>
          <Button onPress={this.enableDarkMode.bind(this)} title={"Toggle darkmode"}>
            <Text>Toggle Darkmode</Text>
          </Button>
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
    }else{
      return (
        <SafeAreaView style={this.styles.container}>
            <Text>Please Wait Loading</Text>
        </SafeAreaView>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are not passing any style to `Text` component as I can see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
<Text style={{ color: this.state.darkmode ? "#EEE" : "#000" }}>darkmode is set to {this.state.darkmode? "Active":"Inactive"}</Text>
```

Basically you need to apply `color` from your Style Class to the `Text` Component, not the `SafeAreaView` which should only keep the `backgroundColor`.

Comment: yeah just found this out, breaks the point of global styles though it now means for every Text in the app I have to do an evaluation for the style...

Comment: @MartinBarker a better solution is to create a new Component for the text. So you won't have to pass the style everytime.

Comment: This is what i have got now, https://pastebin.com/ZTFVANzp, but creating a component how would that have access to something in the topmost component if it was not passed to it?

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the color style prop directly on the Text component.